# MySQL substring function to extract string in a URL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a URL like `{"gclid":"Cj0KEQjw7dfKBRCdkKrvmfKtyeoBEiQAch0egQ97fbdyRpkv6sUmkYHXnTKlOWMywt3SceAol-1umzwaAmsk8P8HAQ","sem_keyword":"+turbolader +einbau","sem_creativeid":"165357442696","sem_matchtype":"b","sem_network":"g","sem_device":"m","sem_placement":"","sem_target":"","sem_adposition":"1t2","sem_param1":"","sem_param2":"","sem_campaignid":"629608072","sem_adgroupid":"38134265464","sem_targetid":"kwd-26982332150","sem_location":"1004645"}`

from where I need to extract `Cj0KEQjw7dfKBRCdkKrvmfKtyeoBEiQAch0egQ97fbdyRpkv6sUmkYHXnTKlOWMywt3SceAol-1umzwaAmsk8P8HAQ`, i.e. the data between two double quotes after `gclid`.
I have tried all substring functions but I'm not able to get even close.

Comment: Is it a json type column or text based?

Comment: it is text based in a mysql table

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL JSON-functions:

```
select json_unquote(json_extract(url, '$.gclid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->gclid;
```

For this to work, `file_get_contents` requires that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. This can be done at runtime by including `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);`